# Suggestions for creating images-to-pdf converter using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a **images-to-pdf converter using Javascript**. And I **want suggestions** how I can create one.

Please Help!

I want user to select multiple images from there computer and combine all the images together and convert them in a single pdf.

**Any kind of help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [jspdf](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf/doc/symbols/jspdf.html) There is pretty good documentation to get you started as well.